# node.js zombie headless browser does not load url

Tags: node.js, zombie.js, jasmine-node

**tools**

- Linux ubuntuG5 3.13.0-48-powerpc64-smp
- node.js v0.10.38
- zombie Version 3.1.0 2015-03-15
- jasmine-node 1.14.3

sample_zombie_spec.js

```
var Browser, assert, browser, url, title;

assert = require('assert');
Browser = require('zombie');

var google = "https://google.com"
var google_title = "Google"

url = google
title = google_title

browser = new Browser();

describe('home page', function() {

    describe('title', function() {
      it('should have a title', function(done) {
        browser.visit(url).then(function() {
          assert.equal(browser.text('title'), title);
          done();
        }).fail(function(err) {
          console.log('Failed with error: ', error);
          done(err);
        });
      });
    });
});
```

This file is in `spec/` so I ran the following command:

```
jasmine-node spec/
```

Results:

```
F

Failures:

  1) home page title should have a title
   Message:
     TypeError: Object [object Promise] has no method 'fail'
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: Object [object Promise] has no method 'fail'
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/dmmmd/Dropbox/node_js_projects/affinity-zombie/spec/sample_zombie_spec.js:21:12)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/async-callback.js:45:37)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

Finished in 0.12 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 skipped
```

I tried the exact same thing on a different machine:

#### tools

- Darwin 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0
- io.js v1.8.1
- zombie Version 4.0.7 2015-04-10
- jasmine-node 1.14.3

Results:

```
F

Failures:

 1) home page title should have a title
  Message:
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
  Stacktrace:
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
   at null.<anonymous> (/Users/dmmmd/Dropbox/node_js_projects/spec/sample_zombie_spec.js:21:12)
   at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/async-callback.js:45:37)
   at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:89:15)

Finished in 0.069 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 skipped
```

I tried some other urls, too, even localhost ones without any success.

JavaScript, node.js, io.js, zombie, and jasmine are all new to me so I am basically just following recipes from the documentation and stackoverflow questions. I would appreciate any suggestions. I suspect I am missing something very simple.

Thanks.